How to add php_oauth extension and enable in xampp-8.0.28 in windows 10 system
I'm running XAMPP on Windows and trying to install OAuth into PHP.

XAMPP version: 8.0.28
Installer: xampp-windows-x64-8.0.28-0-VS16-installer.exe
PHP OAuth DLL: php_oauth-2.0.7-7.4-ts-vc15-x64

PHP.ini Configuration:
;extension="D:\xamp-8.0.2\php\ext\php_oauth.dll"
;extension=oauth
;extension=D:\xamp-8.0.2\php\ext\php_oauth.dll
extension=D:\xamp-8.0.2\php\ext\php_oauth
extension=php_oauth
extension=php_oauth.dll

**ERROR:**
[14-Aug-2024 08:59:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oauth' (tried: D:\xamp-8.0.2\php\ext\oauth (The specified module could not be found), D:\xamp-8.0.2\php\ext\php_oauth.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
[14-Aug-2024 09:04:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\xamp-8.0.2\php\ext\php_oauth.dll' (tried: D:\xamp-8.0.2\php\ext\php_oauth.dll (The specified module could not be found), D:\xamp-8.0.2\php\ext\php_D:\xamp-8.0.2\php\ext\php_oauth.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0


How can I resolve this issue and correctly load the php_oauth.dll extension in PHP 8.0.28?

